# Travelling to Edinburgh from India

Tags: london, edinburgh

I am planning to travel to Edinburgh on 4/July and return to India on 15/July.

I am planning to travel to London and then take a train from there.

Can some one tell me how much time does it take to reach Edinburgh from London and what is the frequency of trains.

Do I need transit visa for that?

Comment: It will be quicker, and possibly cheaper, to get your air ticket extended to fly on to Edinburgh. Also note that the cheapest train tickets, called "Advance" (which is a specific ticket type) are valid on booked train only , no refund, so you would have to allow plenty of spare time to get from the London airport of arrival into/across London for the train departure to Edinburgh.

Comment: @Owain Oh... I will also see if it is cheaper to get air ticket till Edinburgh.. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Owain To do any of what you said, I do not need to take any special permission (visa), right??

Comment: No, as you will remain within the United Kingdom (Scotland, England, Wales and Northern Ireland) which is for visa purposes one country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes between 4.5 and 5.5 hours typically, depending which route and number of stops you choose, and there are around 30 trains per day https://www.thetrainline.com/train-times/edinburgh-waverley-to-london or http://m.nationalrail.co.uk

You’ll need a UK visa but you don’t need a transit visa to travel from London to Edinburgh.

Comment: I often use this site in the planning stages, certainly if the airport is not on the main rail lines (as so often in the UK.) https://www.traveline.info/

Comment: Note, there is a sleeper train every night except Saturday, if that's your scene.

Comment: Don't use The Train Line. They rip you off by charging you a booking fee. Buy the ticket from National Rail's website instead.

Answer (score 2):

Train tickets in the UK are expensive.  I recently flew from London to Glasgow because it was cheaper than taking the train, even counting the total cost including getting a bus from my home in Oxford to Heathrow airport, and a bus from Glasgow airport to the city centre.  London to Edinburgh is about the same distance. There are plenty of flights from London to Edinburgh and you won't even have the expense of getting to the airport, since your plane from India will have already taken you there.

It is possible to get cheaper train tickets (called "Advance tickets") but they can only be used on the train that they're reserved on. If you miss your train, you'll have to buy a full-price ticket, so you'd need to leave lots of time to get from the airport to King's Cross (from where the Edinburgh trains depart).

But maybe you want to travel by train so you can see more of the country.  There are some beautiful views on the section north of Newcastle and Durham Cathedral is another impressive sight.  You can find information about the trains from [National Rail](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/) and other sites.  If you do use another site (maybe they have better user interfaces), use either National Rail or the actual train company's website to buy the ticket, so you avoid booking fees.

You aren't transiting in the UK, so you don't need a transit visa. Transit means entering a country just to make a travel connection to another country: for example, if you were entering the UK only to catch a flight to France. You're entering the UK to visit the UK, so you need a visitor visa.

Comment: Thanks Thanks... My main destination is Edinburgh.. I want to get down in London (starting in India) and take a flight/train to Edinburgh... So, you are saying, I do not need any thing called as transit visa... Just Visa for Edinburgh allows me to get down in London and reach Edinburgh,..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You get visas for countries, not cities. Edinburgh and London are both in the same country: the UK.